# JS style.setProperty not called every time

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, css-variables, setattribute

###### Hi, this is my first question on stackoverflow, so please dont roast me more than necessary :)

i have a function called by a eventListener on mousemove. the function writes the mouse coords to two css variables. Sadly, this does not update on every call of the function for some reason

###### This is the function that is called by the eventListener

```js
var textMoved = false;
var initialCoordinates = {x: 0, y: 0};
var documentRoot = document.querySelector(":root");


// ...

document.addEventListener("mousemove", animateType)


function animateType(e) {
    //check if its the first time the mouse is moving
    if (!textMoved) {
        // if yes, set the initial coordinates
        textMoved = true;
        initialCoordinates = {
            x: (e.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 100,
            y: (e.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 100,
        };
        console.log("initial coordinates", initialCoordinates)
    } else {
        // if not, calculate a offset from the initial coordinates so the text doesn't flick when the mouse is moved the first time
        const {clientX, clientY} = e;
        const x = initialCoordinates.x - (clientX / window.innerWidth) * 100;
        const y = initialCoordinates.y - (clientY / window.innerHeight) * 100;
        documentRoot.style.setProperty("--entry-offset-1", x + "px");
        documentRoot.style.setProperty("--entry-offset-2", y + "px");
        console.log("offset", x, y);
    }
}
```

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(var(--entry-offset-1), var(--entry-offset-2));
}
body {
  padding: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```

https://gifyu.com/image/S7X4m

Somehow, the faster I move my mouse, the laggier it gets. Sometimes its like half a second until the css var is updated. The function is definetly called correctly, the console.log is consistant with the mouse movement. Also, there is no console error or something like that

Why is this not overwriting the css var every time the function is called?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide a [mre] (preferably as a Stack Snippet)?

Comment: On an unrelated note, you can replace `document.querySelector(":root")` with `document.documentElement`.

Comment: Hi @Unmitigated, i added a stack snippet to the post, but it does not reproduce the problem. Thats quite interesting. Any idea what could be the cause of this?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is extremely difficult for us to help with solving a problem we cannot see. I recommend removing parts of your code until the problem stops showing up (then adding back the most recently removed part), in order to get a truly minimal example.

Comment: @Unmitigated I uploaded a short gif so you can see the problem. As you can see, the function is called, but it does not overwrite the css var value very time

Comment: Is this issue reproducible in other browsers (Safari, Firefox, etc.)? This might just be a performance issue in Chrome; browsers typically become a lot slower when Dev tools are open because they have to set up a lot of debugging capabilities. And on top of that, with every movement of your mouse, you are running various calculations and updating CSS variables which synchronously triggers re-rendering. It just seems like your browser might be under a lot of load, and Chrome might be throttling Dev tool updates to compensate. Does the issue somewhat resolve with Dev tools closed?

Comment: You probably want to throttle the calls...

Comment: Nope, the dev-tools do not have any impact on the performance. I got it working now, it was because of an css animation-delay on a totally unrelated element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. It was caused by a css "animation-delay" on a totally unrelated element in the DOM. When i removed it, it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but where are you checking to see if the css var is updated?

The developer tools will only update so often, so even if the css vars are probably being updated correctly you might see a delay there.

Comment: Hi, the css vars update pretty good in dev tools actually, they update live with the object on screen. It is definetly a problem with writing the data to the css var